# Return ajax response on same jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have products with addtocart option against each product in productcatalogue.jsp. I want to add product to cart and show the cart in the same page. This is what i have done.

**jsp+script**

```
<td><a id="cart" href="addtocart${product.id}">Add To Cart</a> </td>

$('#cart').click(function() { 
            $.ajax({    
                url : '/addtocart{id}',
                type : 'GET',
                data : "",              
                success : function(response) {
                $('#Content').html(response);
              }
          }); 
    }); 

<div id="Content" style="display:none">
           <h2>Cart Content(s):</h2>

        </div>
```

I have added the cart contents in a div in this same jsp like above.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("cart")
public class CartController {
    @ModelAttribute("cart")
    public Cart initCart() {
        return new Cart();
    }
    @RequestMapping("addtocart{id}")

    @ResponseBody
    public String addToCart(@PathVariable("id") int id,
                    @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart,Model model)
    {
        Product product = productService.getProductById(id);
            if (product != null) {
            CartLine line = new CartLine();
            line.setProduct(product);
            line.setQuantity(1);

            if (product.getQuantity() > 0) {
                cart.add(line);
            }
            }
            if(product.getQuantity() - 1 >= 0) {
                product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() - 1);
                    }
            else {
                model.addAttribute("message", "Out of Stock!");
                return "error";
                }
                productService.updateProduct(product);

        return "productcatalogue";
    }
```

It just returns "productcatalogue". If i remove @responsebody i don't get any response on the desired div. Firebug just shows the jsp code in response column. Can someone show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to mix the two methods of attaching handlers. Perform both actions in a single click handler, defined and attached in javascript.

In the HTML, all you need to do is associate each "Add to cart" link with a produce id. A `data-` attribute is ideal.

```
<td><a class="addTocart" href="#" data-productid="{product.id}">Add To Cart</a> </td>
```

Notice that the `id` attribute is replaced with `class="addTocart"`, allowing the following code to handle all such links - you can have as many on your page(s) as you like.

```
$('.addTocart').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addtocart/' + $(this).data('productid'),
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(updateCart);
});
```

*You will probably want to send a `quantity` as well as `productID`, thus allowing one or more items to be added (or subtracted) at each hit*

`updateCart` will be a function that accepts the json-decoded server reponse and updates the client-side representation of the cart accordingly.

By defining `updateCart` in some outer scope, it will be available to be called from elsewhere (other event handlers).

Comment: I am getting "Undefined attribute name (data-productID)" warning and also still i don't get response on the div

Comment: My fault, 'productID' should be all lower case. Edited above.

Comment: Ok. Still no response. I have to do any other changes.

Comment: Did you make the change in both places - HTML and javascript?

Comment: I'll need to see a live version of the code. See if you can set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Ok i will do it. Still i get Undefined attribute name (data-productid).but after changing to <!DOCTYPE html > it disappeared. But i don't get response.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is a good move, makes the page HTML5. You shouldn't really be developing anything else these days. Check the URL, I may have messed it up - I think I added a `/` that may need taking back out.

Comment: Yes i removed that. data-productid="{product.id}" is right ? i should not add $ right ??

Comment: Correct, no `$` in the HTML.

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaz6mLcs/) demonstrating the data- attribute being readable by jQuery.

Comment: i understood data- usage. But i am making some other mistake i guess.Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pmpm/jtsv354L/

Comment: how should i define updateCart? This is where i am committing mistake i think.

Comment: Now that you know how to make the ajax call, `updateCart` is the $64000 question. It is really a topic for another question .... after you have made a serious attempt.

Comment: Outside my experience I'm afriad. Where I would start is by getting the overall architecture straight. I would start with the concept that "the cart" itself is server-side in either the session (logged-out/unregistered users) or database (logged-in users). Then, what the user sees is a client-side representation that is kept in synchronism with the server-side cart by a combination of AJAX, JSON and javascript function `updatecart`. This architecture (or similar) will simplify transitions from page-to-page and from logged-out to logged-in state.

Comment: Not yet. Someone else might wing in with other ideas. In particular, I haven't touched your server-side code.